# The images from the webservice are refreshed in the UITableview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I was trying to load images from a web service to my tableview. But the images are refreshed and same image rotate in every cell. I think the problem is due to not implementing caching in proper way. I tried lot of stuff. But no luck..

import UIKit
class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var SLAFImages = [String]()
var SLAFHeading = [String]()
var SLAFText = [String]()
var SLAFCount = [Int]()

@IBOutlet weak var btnAction: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let reposURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.helitours.lk/test.html")
    // 2
    do{
        if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL!) {
            // 3
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                // 4
                if let reposArray = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                    // 5
                    for item in reposArray {
                       if let name = item.valueForKey("title") {

                           SLAFHeading.append(name as! String)
                        }

                        if let Imgname = item.valueForKey("main_image") {
                            let urlimg=("http://airforce.lk/"+(Imgname as! String)) as String;
                             SLAFImages.append(urlimg)
                                                       }
                                              }
                }
            }
        }

    }catch{}

    let infoImage = UIImage(named: "crest png.png")
    let imgWidth = infoImage?.size.width
    let imgHeight = infoImage?.size.height
    let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: imgWidth!, height: imgHeight!))
    button.setBackgroundImage(infoImage, forState: .Normal)
     //button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("openInfo"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    SLAFCount=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    SLAFText = ["While they like to munch on underwater plants, you might ",
        "While they like to munch on underwater plants, you might ",
        "While they like to munch on underwater plants, you might "]

    //SLAFImages = ["Img1.jpg","Img2.jpg","Img3.jpg"]


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return SLAFHeading.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =
    self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "NewsTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        as! NewsTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.NewsHeading.font =
        UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
    cell.NewsHeading.text = SLAFHeading[row]
    if let url = NSURL(string: SLAFImages[row]) {
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, NSHTTPURLResponse, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("thers an error in the log")
            } else {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    cell.NewsImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                }
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
    cell.NewsCount.text=String(SLAFCount[row])
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Use the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) which can save images in cache and load from there.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540785/tableview-cell-show-image-with-dispatch-async-shows-unexpected-non-void-return/37541296#37541296

Comment: You should add else condition to your if let branch in cellForRowAtIndexPath. If no url - load empty UIImage. This may resolve your problem or help to avoid duplicating of images in cells in future.

Comment: @kumar KL.. The images are getting loaded with your code. But when I scroll down the tableview, the images are refreshed and download again. Pls guide

Answer (score 1):

## Download image in Table view cell

Better way
this code will not increase more memory use of app.

```
//Initialize your catch variable 
  var cache = NSCache()
    
// MARK: - Private   Image Download Block here
                private func downloadPhoto(url: NSURL, completion: (url: NSURL, image: UIImage) -> Void) {
                    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, { () -> Void in
                        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                            if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                                    cache.setObject(image, forKey: url)
                                    completion(url: url, image: image)
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
    


//Call this Function from Table view 
 //Step 1
 // Checking here Image inside Catch
           let imageurl = NSURL(string:”Image URL here”)
               let myimage = cache.objectForKey(imageurl!) as? UIImage
    
            //Step 2
            // Downloading here Promotion image
            if myimage == nil {
           downloadPhoto(imageurl!, completion: { (url, image) -> Void in
                    let indexPath_ = self.tblView.indexPathForCell(cell)
                            if indexPath.isEqual(indexPath_) {
                                cell.myImageView.image = image
                            }
                            
                        })
                        
                    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Its working. but when I scroll down the tableview the images are getting refreshed.. So there is a refreshing of images. Sometime wrong image placed in the cell. What should be the change in code.

Comment: This things not happened with this code is fully tested i am using mostly app this code and not faced this types of problems those are you facing. Please check your code properly i think something  you missed.